# Any free java VFS library?

Tags: java, vfs

I'm looking for a free java library which will allow me to organize part of the file system as one physical file. I have **ruled out Apache VFS**, because I need an unique format which will be hard to parse for someone else, not zips, tars, etc. Is there any solution available? 
Thanks for any suggestions.

Edit: random access to the content is also the priority

Comment: Have you considered whether you can put encryption around Apache VFS?

Comment: No, but it doesn't matter as far as Apache VFS does not support random access to the archive content, what is important

Comment: I also don't want to use commons-vfs because it doesn't have directory listings for SFTP :(

Answer (score 0):

Consider the [FS2 project](http://robertjchristian.github.com/fs2/).  It was built as a simple answer to JSR 170. The API is lightweight, and implementing a custom persistence mechanism is easy.

Answer (score 0):

I think this library is perfect
[JBOSS VFS3](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/VFS3UserGuide)